# How do I disable Command + H key combination for a Java Swing Application in OS X

Tags: java, swing, key, combinations, fullscreen

I am building a full screen java swing application for Mac users. This application is to be used for giving online tests and therefore requires the user not to exit from it. I am trying to block the Command + H key combination which hides the application. How do I block this key combination from my application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easier way might be to use a focuslistener and/or a windowstatelistener to capture if the user did hide/ leave the app if so, give them a 0!

Comment: I finally resolved it. used input man and KeyStrokes to detect the keys pressed and handled the KeyReleases through Key Listener. The solution is to detect the above and fire this.setVisible(true); This makes the frame visible again as soon as it hides.

Comment: Great! You should post your solution as the answer and check it